# CSS overflow-x related to body right border instead of wrapping div right border

Tags: css

I have a div for pages content (`<div class="content">`) that should have a width, making text easy to read.

If a table appears it should be allowed that the table overflows content-div but not the page body.

Currently I have this: [overflow-x:auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAQoc.png):

[image]

This is the results of `overflow-x: auto` for `<div class="mytable">`, which is a child element of content-div.

See source:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 70px;
  background-color: #99ccff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #e6f2ff;
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 320px;
  width: 500px;
}

.mytable {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.mytable th {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.mytable td {
  background-color: #e6f2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  My Menu
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
        <li><a href="#">Dolor</a>
          <li><a href="#">Nonumy</a>
            <li><a href="#">Tempor</a>
              <li><a href="#">Invidunt</a>
                <li><a href="#">Labore</a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <div class="mytable">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Sector 1</th>
        <th>Sector 2</th>
        <th>Sector 3</th>
        <th>Current Lap</th>
        <th>Best Lap</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 1</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 2</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 3</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 4</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 5</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 6</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Runner 7</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
        <td>0:21</td>
        <td>0:23</td>
        <td>1:31</td>
        <tD>1:29</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

But what I want is that mytable-div is allowed to expand to the edge of the documents body:

[image]

The scroll bar triggered by `overflow-x: auto` should only appear if the table would overflow the body's right edge:

[image]

I played with position and width:

```
.mytable {
   position: absolute;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

This results that the table flows out bodys right edge, if the browsers window was too smal.

```
.mytable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

This results in a mytable-div with 100% width of the content-div.

Both tries have overlapped the text below the table.

Well I could give a fixed with to mytable-div computed using JavaScript, but if possible I would prefer solving this with pure CSS.

Comment: Nailing the main components of your page into place using fixed positioning, is probably not such a good idea to begin with. If you used a "proper" column layout, then you should probably be able to use one of the techniques outline in https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ to achieve the behavior you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
This hint helps me. I added `position: relative; width: calc(100vw - 420px)` and it works the way I want.

Now `.mytabel` is:

```
.mytable {
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow-x: auto;
     position: relative;
     width: calc(100vw - 420px);
 }
```

Increasing `420px` enlarges the gab to documents body edge.
On resizing the browsers window the gap is kept constant.

[image: Browser window with enougth space for table]

If the window is to small for the table, a scrollbar appears like expected.

[image: Browser window too small for table]